# TortoiseHg Workbench: Manifest window, pops out instead of being part of main window

Tags: tortoisehg

I must be stupid today, but...

In TortoiseHg Workbench, when I right-click a revision and choose 'Browse at rev', a separate Manifest window pops up showing all the files. This window used to be a sub-window of the main window. I'd like it to pop back in, but how? I've tried to kinda drag it in, hoping it would find its way (like the repository window does).

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to be separate window and **expected**

If you want to get manifest inside Workbench, you have to select "Manifest" button in "Tasks" toolbar

[image: Toolbars]

or `Main Menu` - `View` - `Manifest`